# KNIME R integration - Package installation

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets, knime

I am a relatively new user to KNIME. I have been trying to install the 'gWidgetsRGtk2' package through the R snippet, but it keeps throwing me an error when i try to load it.

```
if(require("gWidgetsRGtk2")){
  print("gWidgetsRGtk2 is loaded correctly")
}else{
  print("Trying to install gWidgetsRGtk2")
  install.packages("gWidgets",dependencies=TRUE)

options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")
```

I have tried changing the R path in the global preferences, and also tried adding this package directly into the KNIME-R folder.

None of these methods seem to work. Can anyone suggest a way out?

Comment: I usually have a separate installation for R and install the packages there. Then, I just set the R path in `File`|`Preferences`|`KNIME`|`R`|`Path to R Home` (like: `C:\Users\demo\Documents\R\R-2.15.2`).

Comment: I've tried that already. Doesn't make a difference. Have you tried using this specific package? Wondering if it is a package incompatibility?

Comment: Have you tried this: `install.packages("gWidgetsRGtk2",dependencies=TRUE)`?

Comment: My guess is that `RGtk2` isn't getting installed. Can you check that first: `require(RGtk2)`?

Comment: jverzani - That is the problem. RGtk2 is not getting installed.
landroni - I have tried installing. Throws me error on loading package.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the package installation part ...

- go to `File > Preferences > Knime > R` and
- copy `Path to R Home`
- now open the path (in console or in Explorer)
- execute the R executable in `bin` directory
- the R console used in Knime is all yours